# R: how to save a plotly figure

Tags: r, plotly

```
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(economics, x = ~pop)
```

Using kaleido to save the plot gives me the error,

```
> plotly::kaleido(p = p,
               file = "myplot.png")
Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kaleido'
```

However, I've installed kaleido on my Mac by using `pip install kaleido` in my terminal. Is there another way to save `plotly` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of @RRuiz works. However, if you want to save an interactable plot, you can use the "htmlwidget" package.

```
library(plotly)
x <- 1:100
y <- sin(x)
p <- plot_ly(x=x, y=y, mode="lines")
p

library(htmlwidget)
setwd("path/to/your/folder/with/these/bars")
saveWidget(p, "p1.html", selfcontained = F, libdir = "lib")
```

This will save an html page on your computer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug lately. You could use the workaround like described [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/pull/2228):

```r
# Reinstall latest development version which includes the bugfix
devtools::install_github("quinten-goens/plotly.R@fix/kaleido-export-bug")

library(plotly)
library(reticulate)

p <- plot_ly(economics, x = ~pop)

# Simulate a conda environment to use Kaleido
reticulate::install_miniconda()
reticulate::conda_install('r-reticulate', 'python-kaleido')
reticulate::conda_install('r-reticulate', 'plotly', channel = 'plotly')

save_image(p, file="your_plot.png")
#> No trace type specified:
#>   Based on info supplied, a 'histogram' trace seems appropriate.
#>   Read more about this trace type -> https://plotly.com/r/reference/#histogram
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>